# Failed to set Alarm for a week

Tags: android

I used the following code for setting the alarm for week(Repeating). The following code trigger my service in between 15 to 30 minute. Actually i have configured it for a week

```
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, SyncService.class);
            newIntent.putExtra(Constant.TASK_ID,Constant.PROMPT_ID);
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, newIntent, 0);
            //
long interval = 7 * AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY;
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pIntent);
```

Comment: i guess you need to call pending intent to a broadcast and let broadcast start the service so that you can repeat the alarm for 7 days like using  **PendingIntent.getBroadcast(YourActivity.this, 0, newIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);**